# Elasticsearch matching similar sentences in arrays

Tags: string, elasticsearch, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a chatbot with elasticsearch and I can't figure out how to get it to behave like i want.

I have question objects of this format in an index '/questions/q':

```
{
    "name": "some question" //just for identification,
    "questions": [
        "Is ice cream good?",
        "Is ice cream delicious?",
        "Will i love the taste of ice cream?"
    ],
    "response": "yes"
}
```

I want to match an input question against the questions array where the highest score is the object that has the best single matching question. So essentially i want the score of the object to be the score of the highest question in it's array.

Currently, i'm using a query similar to this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
        "questions": {
          "query": "where can i buy tickets"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

But its giving me very low scores if the array is large because i guess it flattens the array as one big string.

What kind of query should i be using for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use nested datatypes, it will both solve your problem and prevent strings like "is love good?" to match this questions set ?

See why and how at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html